# Make visual studio stop running dev web server when I attach

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, webdev.webserver

Why the heck does visual studio (2012 I'm using, I think previous versions did this too) load the WebDevServer for all web projects in my solution when I tell my solution to **attach** to another process?

If I'm attaching, obviously I don't want it to load processes because I'm debugging an already running process! Gah!

Anyone know how to make it not do this when I'm attaching to another process? This is driving me nuts because the web dev servers load up and try to acquire resources in use by the already running processes I'm trying to attach to..

Answer (score 0):

I have found this occurs on some projects. If you change the project properties > Web > Servers. And the choose "Use Custom Web Server" that will ensure that Visual Studio does nothing when you attach.